# Padding in a sharepoint calculated field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to pad in a calculated field to get a final result length to be standard?

lets say I want my calculated field result to be 8 characters long beginning with MTX then enough zeros to pad and then the ID of the record.

So if the record ID is 23 then the result would be MTX00023

Answer (score 3):

Use the `TEXT` function. Set this as the formula for the calculated field: `="MTX"&TEXT(ID,"00000")`.

*Important note about using the ID field in a calculated field*: When the item is created, its ID is not yet available. After creating an item, you will need to edit it so that the calculated field is updated with the proper ID.